# Twofish file decryption

Tags: c#, encryption

How do you decrypt file encrypted using Twofish algorithm? The only thing I have is a 16 character password and a file encrypted using Twofish and this password.
Any idea?

edit: it can be any programming language

Answer (score 2):

Twofish is not part of the .NET framework so you need to implement your own code to handle the decryption.

Fortunately there is a good article on this here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/twofish_csharp.aspx